# EclipseLink Distributed Cache causing Null Primary Keys, what?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, jpa, eclipselink

Ok, this is going to be long, so here's the `tl;dr`: When distributed cache coordination is enabled, one of the apps slowly starts to degrade in integrity and throws a really strange exception. The 'fix' is to disable caching. Which sucks. Please help us find the issue in EclipseLink so we can patch it!

EclipseLink 2.5.1

We have these Entities:

`@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Identifiable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;
    @Version
    @Column(name = "meta__version")
    private Integer version;
}`

`@Entity
@Table(name = "customers", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "phone_number"), @Index(columnList = "email_address") })
@Cacheable
public class Customer extends Identifiable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;
....
}`

`@Entity
@Table(name = "notes", indexes = { @Index(columnList = "customer_id, is_cleared") })
@Cacheable
public class Note extends Identifiable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    public Customer customer;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id")
    public Agent agent;
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32767)
    @Column(name = "text", length = 32767)
    public String text;
    @Column(name = "is_cleared")
    public Boolean isCleared;
}`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
    version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="databunker">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/databunker</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>databunker.orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <class>com.mycompany.Customer</class>
        <class>com.mycompany.Note</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <!-- un-comment these properties to dump generated SQL -->
            <!-- <property -->
            <!-- name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" -->
            <!-- value="FINE" /> -->
            <!-- <property -->
            <!-- name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" -->
            <!-- value="true" /> -->
            <property
                name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
            <property
                name="eclipselink.ddl-generation"
                value="create-or-extend-tables" />
            <property
                name="eclipselink.weaving.changetracking"
                value="false" />
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.query.timeout"
                value="15000" />
            <property
                name="eclipselink.cache.size.default"
                value="10000" />
            <property
                name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.protocol"
                value="jms" />
            <property
                name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.topic"
                value="openejb:Resource/jms/EclipseLinkTopic" />
            <property
                name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.factory"
                value="openejb:Resource/jms/EclipseLinkTopicConnectionFactory" />
            <property
                name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.jms.reuse-topic-publisher"
                value="true" />
            <property
                name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.remove-connection-on-error"
                value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

We have two apps. App1 does writing/updates on Customers, App2 does writing/updates on Notes. They both use the exact same persistent-unit library jar. After running for awhile, eventually the notes app starts failing with this stack trace for a particular customer object. Restarting the server fixes the problem until it starts occurring for another Customer object.

```
[http-apr-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.mycompany.notes.restapi.RestExceptionMapper - toResponse() unexpected exception
javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:272) ~[geronimo-transaction-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252) ~[geronimo-transaction-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy.completeTransaction(JtaTransactionPolicy.java:328) ~[openejb-core-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.TxRequired.commit(TxRequired.java:75) ~[openejb-core-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.afterInvoke(EjbTransactionUtil.java:76) ~[openejb-core-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:231) ~[openejb-core-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:181) ~[openejb-core-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:268) ~[openejb-core-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:263) ~[openejb-core-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:86) ~[openejb-core-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:303) ~[openejb-core-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.getNotes(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.mycompany.notes.restapi.NoteTakerController.getNotes(NoteTakerController.java:68) ~[NoteTakerController.class:na]
at com.mycompany.notes.restapi.NoteTakerController$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0.getNotes(com/mycompany/notes/restapi/NoteTakerController.java) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180) ~[cxf-api-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[cxf-api-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:165) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:89) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:66) [openejb-cxf-rs-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57) [cxf-api-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:93) [cxf-api-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262) [cxf-api-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:237) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.onMessage(CxfRsHttpListener.java:170) [openejb-cxf-rs-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RsServlet.service(RsServlet.java:53) [openejb-rest-4.6.0.1.jar:4.6.0.1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at com.mycompany.notes.restapi.security.HMACSecurityFilter.doFilter(HMACSecurityFilter.java:79) [HMACSecurityFilter.class:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at com.mycompany.cdi.RequestBufferingFilter.doFilter(RequestBufferingFilter.java:50) [java-common-1.0.10.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45) [tomee-catalina-1.6.0.1.jar:1.6.0.1]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2378) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7197] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [Customer[agent=Agent[agentName=Api User,id=1,version=1],address=Address[streetAddress=somewhere road,city=KANSAS CITY,zipcode=66210,state=State[postalAbbreviation=KS,id=38,version=1],id=298219,version=1],leadStatus=LeadStatus[name=New,id=1,version=1],leadSource=LeadSource[name=IRMS,id=9,version=1],project=Project[campaignName=Outbound59734,id=2,version=1],version=7]], primary key [null]. Set descriptors IdValidation or the "eclipselink.id-validation" property.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:696) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:170) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:527) ~[geronimo-transaction-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:511) ~[geronimo-transaction-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:413) ~[geronimo-transaction-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:262) ~[geronimo-transaction-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException: 
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [Customer[agent=Agent[agentName=Api User,id=1,version=1],address=Address[streetAddress=somewhere road,city=KANSAS CITY,zipcode=66210,state=State[postalAbbreviation=KS,id=38,version=1],id=298219,version=1],leadStatus=LeadStatus[name=New,id=1,version=1],leadSource=LeadSource[name=IRMS,id=9,version=1],project=Project[campaignName=Outbound59734,id=2,version=1],version=7]], primary key [null]. Set descriptors IdValidation or the "eclipselink.id-validation" property.
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nullPrimaryKeyInUnitOfWorkClone(ValidationException.java:1469) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.changetracking.DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.calculateChanges(DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.java:109) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.changetracking.DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.calculateChangesForExistingObject(DeferredChangeDetectionPolicy.java:56) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:664) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1516) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3168) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:352) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158) ~[eclipselink-2.5.2-M1.jar:2.5.2.v20131113-a7346c6]
... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Two things to try to help narrow down the issue are to move the ID From the mappedSupperClass to the Entities, and to check that you are not sharing entities between the persistence units.  Some of the internal weaving optimizations might be interfering with the two persistence units - in particular check how the problem Customer instance was read in.

Comment: Got it. We just removed @MappedSuperclass and copy/pasta all of the code into the entities. We only have one persistence unit per app. The same jar is used in multiple apps in separate JVMs. Letting this run for a day and see if it corrupts itself

Comment: Still had the problem. We're reverting the changes... but thanks. We realized though eclipselink does "update objects" by default, so we're adding `@Cache(coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS)` to everything and giving that a run instead.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipselink does distributed updates by default. Try @Cache(coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS) instead

Comment: How is this an answer ? Did this resolved the issue ? Because for me same error started to occur after adding this coordinationType = CacheCoordinationType.INVALIDATE_CHANGED_OBJECTS

Answer (score 1):

Must be a bug buried deep inside EclipseLink... Disabling another optimization fixed the problem:

```
 <property
         name="eclipselink.weaving.internal"
         value="false" />
```

Bummer.